# How do I run a executable (application/x-executable) file?

Tags: 12.10, executable

I just downloaded Zodiac (a chem software) for linux and I tried using `sudo bash ./Zodiac_linux` from the directory where it's installed and I received the error:

```
./Zodiac_linux: ./Zodiac_linux: cannot execute binary file
```

I am running 12.10 if it's relevant.

Running `file Zodiac_linux` gives the output:

```
Zodiac_linux: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, not stripped
```

The output of `locate libopenbabel` is:

```
/home/username/build_babel/lib/libopenbabel.so
/home/username/build_babel/lib/libopenbabel.so.4
/home/username/build_babel/lib/libopenbabel.so.4.0.2
/usr/lib/libopenbabel.so.4
/usr/lib/libopenbabel.so.4.0.1
/usr/local/lib/libopenbabel.so
/usr/local/lib/libopenbabel.so.4
/usr/local/lib/libopenbabel.so.4.0.2
/usr/share/doc/libopenbabel4
/usr/share/doc/libopenbabel4/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libopenbabel4/copyright
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopenbabel4.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopenbabel4.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopenbabel4.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopenbabel4.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libopenbabel4.shlibs
```

Comment: What's the output of `file Zodiac_linux`?

Comment: Um, I don't understand what you want from me. Just for some background I don't understand much programming so you'll have to explain everything in simple terms for me to understand it. Just tell me what to do.

Comment: Run `file Zodiac_linux` from the directory where it's installed and include the output in your question

Comment: What's the output of `uname -m`?

Comment: You mean what architecture I'm operating on? i686

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bash is a shell, it can't execute binary files.

Presuming the file is already executable, you can simply type `./Zodiac_linux`.

If it isn't executable yet, you can set the executable bit with `sudo chmod +x ./Zodiac_linux` and then run the above command.

Comment: This gives me the output './Zodiac_linux: error while loading shared libraries: libopenbabel.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'

Comment: Do you have Open Babel installed? Maybe you could run a quick `locate openbabel` to check if it exists anywhere.

Comment: Sure do. I installed it just yesterday so I could install the latest version of Avogadro.

Comment: If you can verify that exact file exists (including version number), you can try setting the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/lib/` and then running the program from the same terminal. If it's just that the version is wrong, you _may_ be able to hack around by symlinking libopenbabel.so.2 to e.g. libopenbabel.so.1 (if that exists). Also, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s).

Comment: Simple English please? Might be best to add it to your answer because I am no programmer, you'll have to tell me exactly what to do.

Comment: Ok, first you have to know if/where the file "libopenbabel.so.2" resides. You can find that from executing `locate libopenbabel`. (Could you paste the output?) If you see libopenbabel.so.2, the problem is Zodiac isn't finding the library even though it exists. You need to tell it to look for it by setting the variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/dir/`. Just paste (CTRL+SHFT+V) that with the right directory (found from `locate`) in a terminal.

Comment: I added it to my question. How do I change this variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the directory of the libopenbabel.so.2?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7356/discussion-between-mtdevans-and-brenton-horne)